# Dúvida SQL com uso de subquery e comando IN

Tags: sql, select

Estou precisando fazer o seguinte. Fulano tem vários modelos de carros. Quero listar outros usuários que também tenha 3 modelos específicos de carro que fulano tem.

O que eu fiz:

```
$iduser = id do fulano
$mod1 = modelo de carro 1 de fulano 
$mod2 = modelo de carro 2 de fulano 
$mod3 = modelo de carro 3 de fulano
```

Tenho uma tabela (`user`) para usuários e uma tabela (`user_mod`) para os modelos que cada usuário tem. Então preciso achar outros usuários que estão na tabela user_mod que tenham o mesmo `idmodelo` do fulano para cada um dos 3 modelos de carro de fulano.

```
 SELECT a.* 
 FROM users a 
 WHERE a.IDUser!=$iduser AND ('$idmod1,$idmod2,$idmod3') 
 IN (Select d.IDModelo From user_mod d Where a.IDUser=d.IDUser)
```

Tentei isso, mas não funcionou. Ele sempre considera apenas o `$idmod1`. Ou seja, se o usuário tem este modelo dentro do seu `SELECT`, ele já é listado. Eu queria que fossem listados apenas usuários que tivessem necessariamente os 3 modelos `$idmod1,$idmod2,$idmod3` dentro do resultado do `SELECT` da subquery. Alguém sabe se há algum comando para isso funcionar? Estou usando banco de dados MySQL.

Muito obrigado!

Comment: Você está programando com PHP?

Comment: Sim, mas eu precisaria que essa seleção fosse feita dentro do proprio SQL pq se eu primeiro listar todos os usuários para então fazer um loop no PHP e identificar aqueles que possuem os mesmos 3 modelos de carro, vai rodar muito loop pq são muitos usuários (não sei se era isso que você iria propor).

Comment: Uma solução que encontrei foi fazer 3 subquery, cada uma para um modelo. ('$idmod1) IN (Select d.IDModelo From user_mod d Where a.IDUser=d.IDUser) AND ($idmod2) IN (Select d.IDModelo From user_mod d Where a.IDUser=d.IDUser) AND ('$idmod3') IN (Select d.IDModelo From user_mod d Where a.IDUser=d.IDUser)....

Mas isso nao vai resolver quando forem 10 modelos de carro ao mesmo tempo. Serão 10 subquery e mais um monte de outras condições Where junto. Vai exigir muito do banco de dados.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vou te passar um conceito (como não sei teu banco), mas a ideia é essa:

```
SELECT * FROM users
WHERE iduser IN (
SELECT DISTINCT(iduser)
FROM user_mod
WHERE idmodelo IN ('$idmod1','$idmod2','$idmod3')
GROUP BY iduser
HAVING COUNT(*) >= 3 )
```

Isso trará todos os usuarios que tenham os 3 carros selecionados.

O que fiz:
Filtrei todos os carros da tabela dos modelos de carros, agrupei por usuário, então peguei somente os que a soma dá >=3, e depois puxei da tabela usuarios quem são.

Comment: Pois é, eu fiquei a madrugada toda pensando e cheguei a conclusão de usar o Count mesmo. Mas minha solução com o Count ainda era muito grande. A sua é bem mais simples e direta. Muito obrigado!!

Ps: eu só tive que retirar o DISTINCT para funcionar como desejado com as demais variáveis que existiam no select final. Mas todo o restante funcionou perfeitamente. Muito obrigado!